# Generator for folder / directory dependency graphs for C/C++ #includes

Tags: c++, c, graphs, dependencies

## Requirements

I would like to generate graphs where the dependencies between directories (defined by `#include`)* are drawn and sub-directories are recursively nested within directory nodes.

- Nesting should be possible with at least 2 layers.
- Operating system Windows (preferred), Linux should it be necessary.
- cost less than 100USD (one-time)
- output format preferably [DOT](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html), SVG, PNG

It is required that the actual directories are drawn, not only the dependencies between files.

*: <sub>The dependencies are actually between the files and evaluated by the C-preprocessor.</sub>

## What I found so far

### [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

[Doxygen has been recommended](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/71195/22332) and does quite a good job with its *[directory graphs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_directory_graph)*. *But* it does not draw sub-directories of more than 1 level relatively to the documented directory. This behavior [seems to be intentional](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7663#issuecomment-602723684) - not a bug.

### [cinclude2dot](https://www.flourish.org/cinclude2dot/)

[cinclude2dot has been recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074323/5534993) but this tool does not draw the actual directories.

### [CodeSonar](http://grammatech.com/codesonar)

The author of [this blog article](https://blogs.grammatech.com/visualizing-include-graphs) has, with "a little hacking", fed the output of `gcc -H` to CodeSonar. I can not afford CodeSonar for this feature. But his results are impressive: [image: example]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used DOXYGEN (probably 15 years+ :)), but have you tried [DOXYGEN with EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE tag](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_example_recursive)? I am with the impression it did quite an excellent job in these days (talk 2000-2002).

> EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE If the EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE tag is set to YES then
>   subdirectories will be searched for input files to be used with the
>   \include or \dontinclude commands irrespective of the value of the
>   RECURSIVE tag.

Another possible option, which is worth investigating, is if you can write a simple Python or C script, which would be able to do the job and generate [GraphViz script](http://graphviz.org/), which then can give you the needed graph? I understand this is additional work, which would make my suggestion in vain, and probably way out of your initial question.

Comment: [`EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_example_recursive) does configure where **example code fragments** are searched for (see also [`EXAMPLE_PATH`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_example_path)) analogous to [`RECURSIVE`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_recursive) for the normal input files. So this option is of *no help for the question*.

Generating directory graphs with its dependencies is not trivial. Instead of programming from scratch, extending Doxygen may be an option.